# How to keep an image displayed in a canvas after reloading a page caused by a click function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have in my project, two canvas to display images.
The first one displays an image following an upload.
I'm trying to duplicate this image in a second canvas after a click to analyze the image.
I notice that the image is duplicated when you click, but it disappears when the function ends and the page is reloaded. Would you have a solution for me, please?

I tried to wait for the loading with $(window).on('load') but it doesn't change anything.

index.ejs

```
<input type="file" name="filename" id="file-to-google" accept="image/*">
```

first canvas

```
<div id="google_canvas_container" class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="google_canvas">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas
    </canvas>
</div>

<div class="input-group" id="analyze-with-google">
    <button id="google_submit" class="btn btn-info" >
        Analyser avec GOOGLE
    </button>
</div>
```

second canvas

```
<canvas id="newCanvas"></canvas>
```

scripts.js

```
const createGoogleCanvas = (canvas ,ctx) => {
    $('#file-to-google').on('change',function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            if (this.files[0].type.match(/image\//)) {
                $('#file_name').attr('value', this.files[0].name);
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    const img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function () {
                        ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
                        ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    };
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            } else {
                alert('Invalid file type');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Please select a file');
        }
    })
}

$('#file-to-google').on('click',function() {
    const canvas = $('#google_canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
    createGoogleCanvas(canvas ,ctx);
});

$('#analyze-with-google').on('click', function() {
    const imgSrc = document.getElementById('google_canvas')
    copyImage(imgSrc);
})

const copyImage = (imgSrc) => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('newCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let img = imgSrc;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
```

Comment: Persisting any in-page data works the same way, even for an image. In this case you can convert the image to Base64 and stash it in Localstorage.

Comment: Thank you.
If I understand correctly, I should be able to retrieve the image from the LocalStorage by converting it to base64. Is that correct?
Do you have an example to make this happen, please?

Comment: LocalStorage stores text, so you need to convert the image to Base64 to store it, then convert it back to bits on the retrieval.

Comment: Do you need the page to reload? Adding `type="button"` to your `button` would prevent the page reloading when it is clicked.

Comment: Yes, I need the page to reload. The clicked button allows me to submit the image to an API that analyzes it and sends back data. I display the data and I actually want to display the canvas next to the data to compare.